# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 _OBJC_CLASS_Foo referenced from: unit test

Tags: iphone, unit-testing

I am about to go nuts ... I can't figure out the correct settings for my Xcode project + unit  (logic and application) testing targets.

I've done step by step many tutorials on how to set unit testing targets including [Apple's](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/02-Setting_Up_Unit_Tests_in_a_Project/setting_up.html) and [Cocoa with Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/12/sample-iphone-application-with-complete.html) and I get the same problem.

I have four targets:

1. MyApp - 
   No dependencies, Runs normally.
2. LogicTests -
   Dependencies: MyApp
   Tests work fine.
3. ApplicationTests - Dependency: MyApp. *Bundle Loader* is set to `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/MyApp.app/MyApp` and *Test Host* to `$(BUNDLE_LOADER)`. Tests work but I get ugly warnings:

   > Class Foo is implemented in both /var/.../MyAppTesting.app/MyApp and /private/var/.../ApplicationTests.octest/ApplicationTests. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

   I think It is because I made Foo.m member of ApplicationTests target.
   I've checked Apple's sample and they don't do such a thing but If I remove Foo.m from the ApplicationTests target then I get:

   > Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Foo", referenced from: Objc-class-ref in FooTest.o`

   How can I solve this? If I my understanding is correct then ApplicationTests target should be able to load any class from MyApp since it has it as a dependency. :(

   Help please.
4. MyAppTesting - 
   Duplicate of MyApp used for unit test debugging breakpoints, etc (?)
   I cannot run this, I get the same Warning as above and the app crashes without launching with Segment fault 11. No test is performed.
   I think the origin of this is the same as above... I hope I am not wrong here.

**EDIT:** 
Why I am warned about Foo implemented in MyAppTesting and ApplicationTests if I am testing ApplicationTests which only depends on MyApp ? Currently, no target depends on MyAppTesting.